# C# find mouse location over AxShockwaveFlashObject control

Tags: c#, mouse-cursor, mouse-position, axshockwaveflash

I have below code which gives me mouse location using `Form1._MouseMove` event, I also captured mouse location over `pictureBox` control using the same event and the same code.

The Code:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            yAxis = (((768 / 2) - Cursor.Position.Y) * 45 / (768 / 2));
            xAxis = (((1024 / 2) - Cursor.Position.X) * 45 / (1024 / 2));

            player.FlashVars = string.Format("YAxis={0}&Rot={1}", yAxis, xAxis);
        }
```

The problem is, I have `AxShockwaveFlashObject` and I need the mouse location over that too but the above code does not work on this control because it doesn't have `AxShockwaveFlashObject1._MouseMove` event. Can anyone please help me to solve this?

Note:

`e.Location.X` & `e.Location.Y` gave me same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below code to add `MouseMove` event to my control and assign `Form1._MouseMove` to it:

```
this.Controls["AxShockwaveFlashObject1"].MouseMove +=Form1_MouseMove;
```